# Private images with Airflow KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am getting started with Airflow and trying to use the KubernetesPodOperator, but I am having trouble with downloading images from private registries. I did some research but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Putting it simply: can I use private images from DockerHub with the KubernetesPodOperator?

Comment: Have you managed to work this out? Can't make it work :-(

Comment: I haven't tried since. Airflow is quite buggy and not very good at heavy-duty jobs, so we kind of abandoned it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [pod_generator.PodGenerator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.10.0rc4/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_generator.py#L28) accepts some kind of object `kube_config` that [knows about imagePullSecrets](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.10.0rc4/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_generator.py#L142), but unfortunately [`KubernetesPodOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.10.0rc4/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py#L87) doesn't provide any such `kube_config` to `PodGenerator`

As best I can tell, it's just an edge case that slipped through the cracks, although it looks like there is [a Jira for that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2854) which matches up with [a corresponding GitHub PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3697), but it isn't clear from looking at the changed files that it will 100% solve the problem you are describing. Perhaps weigh in on either the PR, or the Jira, or maybe even both, to ensure it is addressed.

Comment: Bummer! Oh well, at least Cloud Composer supports private repos from Cloud Container Registry. That will do it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The KubernetesPodOperator accepts an imagePullSecret since version 1.10.1

```
:param image_pull_secrets: Any image pull secrets to be given to the pod.
                           If more than one secret is required, provide a
                           comma separated list: secret_a,secret_b
:type image_pull_secrets: str
```

References:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py

Answer (score 0):

As of Airflow Version 5, to access a private image using `KubernetesPodOperator` you must create a Kubernetes Secret representing credentials to your image and provide this secret object as an argument to your `KubernetesPodOperator`.

More info here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#how-to-use-private-images-container-registry